Trigger Elementor Pop Up using JavaScript
I am new here and not a lot of coding experience,
I am creating an interactive "Building" image map using image map pro plugin in Wordpress, the goal is to have a shape trigger an Elementor Pop Up.
If you visit https://davenuevallarta.com/UNITS/ and click on Get Price List you can see the pop up works correctly. The pop up has Open By Selector (a[href="#PH08"]), and the button targets (#PH08).
enter image description here
But according to the support team of the image map plugin, I need to use JS function to trigger this action. I can insert a JS in each shape, currently i have console.log('Pop-up link clicked2') and when clicking on the image that says PH-08 the console displays the message correctly.
enter image description here
I dont know how to make the next step, the actual triggering of my pop up.
PS if you have any suggestions or alternatives on how to create the interactive building section I'm all ears. The idea is to create something like this one https://quartier.mx/
Thank you very much! :)
I tryed the following code
`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Función para abrir el pop-up
    function openPopup() {
        $('a[href="#PH08"]').click();
    }

    // Asigna el evento click a la forma específica
    $('#shape-id').on('click', function() {
        openPopup();
    });
});


    `
Returned the following error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at Plugin.performClickAction (image-map-pro.min.js?ver=5.6.9:4:76169)
at Plugin.handleEventEnd (image-map-pro.min.js?ver=5.6.9:4:64926)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (image-map-pro.min.js?ver=5.6.9:4:52172)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2:40035)
at v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2:38006)`


"I tryed the following code" - entered into the "Script to run" field your screenshot showed, where you previously had only the console.log statement? Then the error message is most likely simply referring to the < of <script type="text/javascript"> - the plugin expects you to input just JS code there, not surrounded by <script> tags.

I can confirm the following script works as intended
'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
console.log('jQuery is ready');


function openPopup() {
    var link = $('a[href="#PH08"]');
    if (link.length) {
        link.click();
        console.log('Attempting to open pop-up');
    } else {
        console.error('Pop-up link not found');
    }
}

openPopup();

});

It appearse that the comments were affecting the code in the plugin js section.
The following code triggers the pop up and logs the console correctly,


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('jQuery is ready');

   
    function openPopup() {
        var link = $('a[href="#PH08"]');
        if (link.length) {
            link.click();
            console.log('Attempting to open pop-up');
        } else {
            console.error('Pop-up link not found');
        }
    }

    openPopup();
}); 



Thank you!
